# Will disparity in image format/quality between binary classifications affect training of Convolutional Neural Network?

Tags: python, image-processing, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have an image dataset containing two classes. One of the classes has many images and they are all JPG images with the following format:

```
Horizontal/Vertical Resolution: 96 dpi
Bit depth: 24
Size: ~217 KB
```

The other class contains images which I (for the most part) have had to create myself. There are a few that are from the original dataset but the rest are created outside of it. These images have a format like so:

```
Horizontal/Vertical Resolution: 120 dpi
Bit depth: 32
Size: ~2.75 MB
```

Both image classifications are of type `.jpg` and have the same height x width dimensions

During training, all of these files will be reduced in size and converted to a Python numpy array using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.transform import resize

np.array([resize(imread(str(fileName)), (width, height, channels)) for fileName in list_of_filenames])
```

This gives me one batch of images that have been read from a directory, reduces their size to the specified height/width, and puts them into a numpy array.

My question is, with the disparity in image size, bit depth, and dpi will my image classifier simply become a classifier for the image format itself rather than the content of the image? And how would the differences in the images affect the resize function?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think it's likely that what you describe would happen here. You can try to counter bit depth issue by normalising everything to 0-1 (which you will likely do anyway) but even with that you are probably trying to compare apples and oranges here. My question is, why not just do a pre-processing step to make the two datasets exactly comparable? Reduce the resolution and bit depth of the second dataset outside of python/numpy.

Comment: The function above does convert everything to 0-1 so that should be taken care of. I understand that I could try to do that but I'm still doing the processing from different base images. I'd think if the answer to my question were yes then that might still throw things off. I'm sure better understanding of .jpg format would help me in this endeavor.